# Is there any way of making this true: $ 0 \leq \lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow(\infty,0)} xy \leq \epsilon $

Tags: calculus, limits

Is there any conditions that make the following sentence exist?

$$
0 \leq \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(\infty,0)} xy \leq \epsilon
$$

Comment: You're asking about $\infty\times 0$ in disguise, aren't you?

Comment: What do you mean by $\lim_{(x,y)\to(\infty,0)}f(x,y),$ exactly? Without a precise definition, we can't really say anything about it.

Comment: Yeah @PeterTamaroff, it's disguised, I am reading a paper that has that limit, and it only says in the footnote: this limite may exist if an appropriated path to x and y is chosen. I tryed wolfram alpha, but it says something similar: "(limit does not exist) (value may depend on x,y path in complex space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of $$\tag1 \lim_{(x,y)\to(\infty,0)}f(x,y)=c$$ is that $(x,y)\approx(\infty,0)$ should imply $f(x,y)\approx c$.
While $y\approx 0$ can be made more precise with epsilotics to mean $|y|<\epsilon$ for (small) positive  $\epsilon$, this is not possible with $\infty$. 
Instead, we understand $x\approx\infty$ to stand for $x> L$ for (big positive) $L$. Thus (1) translates as
$$\tag2 \forall \epsilon>0\colon\exists \delta>0\colon\exists L\colon 
\forall x>L\colon\forall |y|<\delta\colon |f(x,y)-c|<\epsilon.$$
With $f(x,y):=xy$, (2) does not hold (no matter what $c$ we choose).

However, along a specific path, e.g. substituting $x=\frac1{t^2}$ and $y=42t^2$ with $t\to0$, a result may be obtained (in this case $\lim_{t\to0}\frac1{t^2}42t^2=42$.